# How can I optimize this Bokeh CustomJS plot so changes load more quickly?

Tags: python, pandas, data-visualization, bokeh, bokehjs

Here is a MRE for a plot I made using Bokeh 2.3.2. The actual data set contains around a hundred projects which each have up to 10 tasks and are stored in a df with apprixmately 40k rows. When I save this plot to .html, the file sizes are near 100k KB. Each time users pick a new project via the dropdown, load times can be greater than 10 seconds. I spent quite a bit of time getting the CustomJS code to work how it is now, but would like to reduce load time if possible. Any ideas on how to do this? Bokeh Server is not an option at this time.

```
import itertools
from time import strftime
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Timestamp
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models import GroupFilter, CDSView
from bokeh.models import CustomJS
from bokeh.models import Legend, LegendItem
from bokeh.models.widgets import Select
from bokeh.layouts import row, column
from bokeh.palettes import Set1 as palette

data = {'date': {0: Timestamp('2021-09-26 00:00:00'),
  1: Timestamp('2021-09-26 00:00:00'),
  2: Timestamp('2021-09-26 00:00:00'),
  3: Timestamp('2021-10-03 00:00:00'),
  4: Timestamp('2021-10-03 00:00:00'),
  5: Timestamp('2021-10-03 00:00:00'),
  6: Timestamp('2021-10-10 00:00:00'),
  7: Timestamp('2021-10-10 00:00:00'),
  8: Timestamp('2021-10-10 00:00:00'),
  9: Timestamp('2021-10-03 00:00:00'),
  10: Timestamp('2021-10-03 00:00:00'),
  11: Timestamp('2021-09-26 00:00:00'),
  12: Timestamp('2021-09-26 00:00:00'),
  13: Timestamp('2021-10-10 00:00:00'),
  14: Timestamp('2021-10-10 00:00:00')},
 'TB': {0: 4.1,
  1: 8.5,
  2: 0.2,
  3: 0.2,
  4: 5.1,
  5: 8.5,
  6: 8.5,
  7: 6.1,
  8: 0.2,
  9: 7.0,
  10: 12.5,
  11: 5.9,
  12: 10.1,
  13: 6.9,
  14: 12.6},
 'project': {0: 'Project_A',
  1: 'Project_A',
  2: 'Project_A',
  3: 'Project_A',
  4: 'Project_A',
  5: 'Project_A',
  6: 'Project_A',
  7: 'Project_A',
  8: 'Project_A',
  9: 'Project_B',
  10: 'Project_B',
  11: 'Project_B',
  12: 'Project_B',
  13: 'Project_B',
  14: 'Project_B'},
 'project_sub': {0: 'TASK_1',
  1: 'TASK_2',
  2: 'TASK_3',
  3: 'TASK_3',
  4: 'TASK_1',
  5: 'TASK_2',
  6: 'TASK_2',
  7: 'TASK_1',
  8: 'TASK_3',
  9: 'TASK_2',
  10: 'TASK_1',
  11: 'TASK_2',
  12: 'TASK_1',
  13: 'TASK_2',
  14: 'TASK_1'}}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

dfp_dict = {}

for p in df['project'].unique().tolist():
    df_slice = df.loc[df['project'].isin([p])]
    dfp = df_slice.pivot_table(values='TB', index=df_slice.date, columns='project_sub', aggfunc='max')
    dfp.columns = [p + ', ' + x for x in dfp.columns]
    dfp['project'] = p
    dfp_dict[p] = dfp

# make one big df where each col is 'project name, task'
df_cat = pd.concat([dfp_dict[x] for x in list(dfp_dict)], axis=0)

# this is used for varea plot
df_cat['y1'] = 0

# move project column to end, making it easier to iterate over only columns we want to plot
df_cat = df_cat[[ col for col in df_cat.columns if col != 'project'] + ['project']]

# bokeh datetime axis misbehaving, so give it date string for y axis 
df_cat["date_string"] = df_cat.index.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

#make a nice list of contrasting colors that is big enough for all possible tasks
colors = itertools.cycle(palette[9])    

color_list = []

for color in zip(range(df_cat.shape[1]), colors):
    color_list.append(color[1])

y1 = range(df_cat.shape[0])

source = ColumnDataSource(df_cat)

p = figure(plot_height = 500,
               plot_width = 900,
           x_axis_type="datetime",
           sizing_mode="scale_both",
           active_drag="pan")

project_filter = GroupFilter(column_name='project',
                             group=df_cat['project'].unique().tolist()[0])

# this creates a subset of df_cat by selecting rows from the project column that match dropdown
view = CDSView(source=source, filters=[project_filter])

custom_js_dict = {}
legend_list = []

for i, col in enumerate(df_cat.columns[0:-3]):
    x = p.varea(x='date', y1='y1', y2=col, source=source, view=view, name=col, alpha=0.5, color=color_list[i])
    # save the column name and its renderer so we can create bokeh Legend items
    legend_list.append((col, [x]))


p.yaxis.axis_label="TB"
p.xaxis.axis_label = "Date"

custom_js_dict['f'] = view.filters[0]
custom_js_dict['p'] = p
custom_js_dict['view'] = view
custom_js_dict['projects'] = df_cat['project'].unique().tolist()


# add each project's legend items to the custom_js_dict as bokeh legend item objects
for x in df_cat['project'].unique():
    custom_js_dict[x] = Legend(items=[y for y in legend_list if y[0].split(',')[0] == x])


p.add_layout(custom_js_dict[df_cat['project'].unique().tolist()[0]])
p.legend.click_policy="hide"
p.legend.label_text_font_size = "10pt"


for f in view.filters:
    f.js_on_change('group', CustomJS(args=custom_js_dict,
                                     code="""

            const allProjects = projects

            for (var element of allProjects) {
              if(element === f.group){
              eval(element).visible = true;
              p.add_layout(eval(f.group));
              eval(f.group).click_policy="hide"
              } else {eval(element).visible = false;
              }
                }

            view.properties.filters.change.emit()                     
            """))

project_select = Select(title="Project:", value="", options=df['project'].unique().tolist())
project_select.js_link('value', project_filter, 'group')


show(row(p, column(project_select)))
```

Comment: Well, for a start, `custom_js_dict['projects']` contains duplicates, so if you have 40k rows and only a few projects, then it could be adding tens of thousands of very expensive but pointless iterations to the JS loop. I'd start by calling `unique` on the series before putting it in the dict. Also, as gentle suggestion to help others help you: it would also be advised to trim your MRE down considerably, e.g remove all formatting that is not related directly the problem, condense imports, etc. The code above does not represent the *minimal* in "minimal reproducing example".

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I spent quite a bit of time condensing my original example, but removed some additional non-essential imports and formatting just now. I also added `unique()` to this line `custom_js_dict['projects'] = df_cat['project'].unique().tolist()` which makes sense and substanially reduces the dict values. However,  it didn't seem to impact the performance on the full data set.

Answer (score 2):

I would organize the code differently, to avoid the adding layouts and `eval` calls in the `CustomJS`. Here is the relevant portion of the code:

```py
projects = list(df_cat['project'].unique())

legends = {
    project : Legend(items=[y for y in legend_list if y[0].split(',')[0] == project],
                     click_policy="hide", visible=False, label_text_font_size = "10pt")
    for project in projects
}

for legend in legends.values():
    p.add_layout(legend)
legends[projects[0]].visible = True

custom_js_dict['legends'] = legends
custom_js_dict['f'] = view.filters[0]
custom_js_dict['view'] = view
custom_js_dict['projects'] = projects

for f in view.filters:
    f.js_on_change('group', CustomJS(args=custom_js_dict,
                                     code="""
            for (const project of projects) {
              legends[project].visible = project === f.group;
            }
            view.properties.filters.change.emit()
            """))

project_select = Select(title="Project:", value=projects[0], options=projects)
project_select.js_link('value', project_filter, 'group')
```

This works the same as the original code does, AFAICT, and is about as stripped-down as I can imagine making it. If this still performs poorly with the full data set then you would need to somehow synthesize (or link to) data that can be used to actually reproduce the situation locally (and/or update the MRE to include whatever important pertinent details are missing).

Comment: Thanks for this. I tried it on the full data. It does produce the same output, but I didn't notice a speedup during project selection. I'll have to dig in with a profiler and see if anything stands out.